# How to make a repeating event for a calendar?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a calendar control and when a date is selected it displays a table with the events that are associated with that date from the database. The `Event` table has a repeat column. If the repeat is yes for a certain event then on every day it should display that event.

Ex.

```
Event_id    Event Start Event End   Repeat  Days               Date
2           15:00:00    17:00:00    yes     Monday:Wednesday   10/11/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

This should display every monday and wednesday from 15:00 to 17:00. The `Date` is the first day to start.

This is what I have tried, but it only works for one day.

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    int event_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
    TimeSpan eventStart = reader.GetTimeSpan(2);
    TimeSpan eventEnd = reader.GetTimeSpan(3);
    int repeat = reader.GetInt32(4);
    string days = reader.GetString(5);
    DateTime theDate = reader.GetDateTime(7);

    //Printing the table.
    htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + event_id + "</td><td>" + eventStart + "</td><td>" + eventEnd + "</td><td>" + repeat + "</td><td>" + days + "</td><td>" + theDate + "</td></tr>";  
}
```

Comment: If your question is _"How can I implement calendar event recurrence in C#?"_, then that's too broad for Stack Overflow. Library advice is offtopic too, but I'd suggest using a library like [DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) to calculate recurring events.

Comment: How can you make the variable `repeat` an `int` if it is a string in your Database?

Comment: That was just a typo. It was normally int for 0 or 1, and I changed  last minute but forgot to change both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple approach and may(is) not be the best, but this doesnt require other libraries.

Take all events[repeat(only yes), Day, Date] from database and put into a collection. Then get `selectedDate` and see if `Date` is before or after, if it is before then check if the `selectedDate` is the same as `Days` from the collection if yes then print that collection also.